# Rotate canvas' 2D context exactly 180 degrees

Tags: canvas, matrix, html5-canvas

After rotating a canvas' 2D context by 180 degrees (PI radians) the a-d components of the transform matrix come out as:

```
{
    a: -0.9999999999999962,
    b: -8.742278000372475e-8,
    c: 8.742278000372475e-8,
    d: -0.9999999999999962
}
```

The expected values are:

```
{
    a: -1,
    b: 0,
    c: 0,
    d: -1
}
```

I assume that this is a rounding error due to the use of Math.PI. I'd like this to be exact because if the transformation values aren't whole integers subsequent translations will not be in whole pixels. I'd like to avoid the browser having to do any anti-aliasing of half pixels for performance reasons.

It's not possible for me to round these values after the fact by getting and setting context.currentTransform because the application will be running in a webview on an iPad and as far as I can tell this is unsupported.

Is anyone aware of a way of achieving any of the following:

1. Rotating a context exactly 180 degrees without the rounding errors
2. Setting the a-d values of a transformation matrix without affecting the e and f values (without context.currentTransform)
3. Forcing a canvas to not use anti-aliasing

Any of the above will solve my problem. Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you know what you want to do, but you're just not aware you can call the transform manually using: `ctx.setTransform(a, b, c, d, e, f);`  link for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform

Comment: I need to maintain the e and f values of the matrix though. Is it possible to set a-d without overwriting these? Or is it possible to get these values first without currentTransform?

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but you could do what others have done and apply the transforms yourself, thus giving you full access to matrix at all times. https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/04/26/html5-canvas-games-tracking-transformation-matrices/

Comment: Thanks for the link, this might be what I have to do.